# Swift: Assign an instance of a generic type to a class variable?

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to use this https://github.com/bricklife/JSONRPCKit . It is a simple implementation of JSONRPC for Swift.

This is the example in the readme. Quite simple.

```
// Generating request JSON
let batchFactory = BatchFactory(version: "2.0", idGenerator: NumberIdGenerator())
let request = Subtract(minuend: 42, subtrahend: 23)
let batch = batchFactory.create(request)
batch.requestObject // ["jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "subtract", "params": [42, 23], "id": 1]

// Parsing response JSON
let responseObject: Any = ["jsonrpc": "2.0", "result": 19, "id": 1]
let response = try! batch.responses(from: responseObject)
```

I would like to keep track of `batch`, even if it is created in a function of a class. So that another function (when I get a reply from my server). Can access the specific request/batch/batchelement and execute whatever function it needs to.

I cannot create vars in my class using any of the types from JSONRPCKit.

I get compiler errors along the lines of:

> Protocol 'Batch' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

> Reference to generic type 'Batch1' requires arguments in <...>

> Value of protocol type 'Request' cannot conform to 'Request'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

I tried using the generic in functions somehow to avoid my issues but that didn't help either.

```
    func store_b<Batch: JSONRPCKit.Batch>(_ batch: Batch){
```

---

More info: `batch` is of type `Batch1`, like so:

```
public struct Batch1<Request: JSONRPCKit.Request>: Batch {
```

and `Batch` is a protocol

```
public protocol Batch {
```

Is there a simple way to keep track of my `batch` request and get responses/ how do I use these **generics** properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break down the create method signature and the Batch1 type

```
public func create<Request: JSONRPCKit.Request>(_ request: Request) -> Batch1<Request>

public struct Batch1<Request: JSONRPCKit.Request>: Batch {
    public typealias Responses = Request.Response
    public typealias Results = Result<Request.Response, JSONRPCError>
}
```

`create` is a generic function that takes a single parameter of *any type*. The constraint `<Request: JSONRPCKit.Request>` specifies that the parameter's type must conform to the protocol `JSONRPCKit.Request`.

`Batch1` is a generic struct that needs to define two internal types, both of which are associated with some *arbitrary type*. Again, `<Request: JSONRPCKit.Request>` specifies that that arbitrary type must conform to the protocol `JSONRPCKit.Request`.

The return type `Batch1<Request>` ties these two generics together, saying that the type used for the returned `Batch1` struct will match the type of the `request` parameter.

When you call the create method, you must fill in the generic type with a concrete type, as in the example

```
let batch = batchFactory.create(Subtract(minuend: 42, subtrahend: 23))
```

Now the compiler can go through all of the definitions and create concrete implementations for that type:

```
public func create(_ request: Subtract) -> Batch1<Subtract>

public struct Batch1<Subtract>: Batch {
    public typealias Responses = Int
    public typealias Results = Result<Int, JSONRPCError>
}
```

This uses the fact that `Subtract` defines `typealias Response = Int`. Note that nothing is generic anymore; these are all concrete types. You would have no issue with trying to store a property of type `Batch1<Subtract>`.

---

This is why you can't easily store the batch in a property: Swift has no idea what types to put in it!

One way around this is to instead store a closure, this can wrap the generic batch such that the class doesn't have to know about it

```
// closure property
var responseProcessor: ((Any) -> Void)?

func createBatch<R: JSONRPCKit.Request>(request: R, processor: @escaping (R.Response) -> Void) {
    let batch = batchFactory.create(request)
    self.responseProcessor = { responseObject in
        let response = try! batch.responses(from: responseObject)
        processor(response)
    }
}

// somewhere else when you get the responseObject
responseProcessor?(responseObject)
```

This method takes a specific closure that matches the generic type and wraps it in a closure that is no longer dependent on the generic. This way every batch can share the same closure property.